# will facebook sharer functionality be supported?

Tags: facebook, share

I know that fb_share button is deprecated and devs are recommended to use like button.
Can we safely use http://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= link to provide ability of sharing some news from our site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The brief answer is YES. Facebook cares about backward compatibility.